# Calculate mean and sd by ID and Day within a column

Tags: r, identity-column

I'm new to R and need to summarize mean and sd of my data in a new table:

The raw data look like that:

```
ID    Day    pH
1      1      7
1      1      7.2
1      1      7.1
2      1      7.3
2      1      7.4
2      1      7.2
3      1      7
3      1      7.1
3      1      7.5
4      1      7.3
4      1      7.2
4      1      7.6
1      2      7
1      2      7.2
1      2      7.1
2      2      7.1
2      2      7.4
2      2      7.2
3      2      7.5
3      2      7.1
3      2      7.5
4      2      7.2
4      2      7.2
4      2      7.3
1      3      7.4
1      3      7.2
1      3      7.1
2      3      7.2
2      3      7.4
2      3      7.2
3      3      7.4
3      3      7.2
3      3      7.5
4      3      7.4
4      3      7.2
4      3      7.7
```

And the table I want should look like:

```
ID    Day    pHmean   pHsd
1      1      7.1      0.10
2      1      7.3      0.10
3      1      7.2      0.26
4      1      7.4      0.21
1      2      7.1      0.10
2      2      7.2      0.15
3      2      7.4      0.23
4      2      7.2      0.06
1      3      7.2      0.15
2      3      7.3      0.12
3      3      7.4      0.15
4      3      7.4      0.25
```

And then I want to create an barplot with error bars showing the pH value on the y-achsis and the ID on the x-achsis with the days in different coloured bars.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: The plot really is a separate question.  At least try something.  google R + barplot.  Being new to R means you have to work on your own a bit to understand how it works.  Right now this has the feel of please do this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Posted as a solution as there was some discussion of if this works (could be R version or something):

```
aggregate(pH~ID+Day, dat, function(x) round(c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)), 2))

## > aggregate(pH~ID+Day, dat, function(x) round(c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)), 2))
##    ID Day pH.mean pH.sd
## 1   1   1    7.10  0.10
## 2   2   1    7.30  0.10
## 3   3   1    7.20  0.26
## 4   4   1    7.37  0.21
## 5   1   2    7.10  0.10
## 6   2   2    7.23  0.15
## 7   3   2    7.37  0.23
## 8   4   2    7.23  0.06
## 9   1   3    7.23  0.15
## 10  2   3    7.27  0.12
## 11  3   3    7.37  0.15
## 12  4   3    7.43  0.25
```

Comment: What R version are you using? This still does not work for me?

Comment: I assume you are on R 3.0.0 - I found this line in the news; *aggregate() gains a formula method thanks to a contribution by Arni Magnusson. The data frame method now allows summary functions to return arbitrarily many values.* This is very useful to me and I am upgrading now.

Comment: +1 for using in one function call and for making me upgrade R

Comment: @DidzisElferts to my shame I am (sorry ***was***) on 2.15.2 at work (Win64)

Comment: @DidzisElferts and Tyler, just to confirm this now works for me with brand spanking new R 3.0.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It helped a lot!!

Comment: @TylerRinker, what do you get when you run `str` on the output? I find that when using multiple aggregation functions, I have to do a `do.call(data.frame, inputdf)` to get the multiple aggregated outputs as separate columns.

Comment: Yes you're correct, it depends on what you're using this for.  That was an aspect of aggregate I don't like.  For most jobs I use `split` `lapply` `do.call(rbind` workflow.  There's other alternatives but it always works for me.

Comment: @TylerRinker, It might be worth editing your post to include something about this, because a matrix as a column might be confusing for a new user.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `aggregate` function like so...

```
pHmean <- aggregate( pH ~ Day + ID , data = dat , FUN = mean )[,3]

dat <- cbind( aggregate( pH ~ Day + ID , data = dat , FUN = sd ) , pHmean )
dat
   Day ID         pH   pHmean
1    1  1 0.10000000 7.100000
2    2  1 0.10000000 7.100000
3    3  1 0.15275252 7.233333
4    1  2 0.10000000 7.300000
5    2  2 0.15275252 7.233333
6    3  2 0.11547005 7.266667
7    1  3 0.26457513 7.200000
8    2  3 0.23094011 7.366667
9    3  3 0.15275252 7.366667
10   1  4 0.20816660 7.366667
11   2  4 0.05773503 7.233333
12   3  4         NA 7.400000
```

Comment: Or `aggregate(pH~ID+Day, dat, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x)))` there's about 100 ways to approach this one.

Comment: @TylerRinker that won't work. You can't use multiple aggregation functions in the same function call. I know there are many ways to do this, I am just suggesting one way. Which works!

Comment: you can if you pass it an anonymous function that combines the two.  Just tried it and it does work though with poorly named columns.  `aggregate(pH~ID+Day, dat, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))` would be better.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the output from that function call. I do not get a mean and SD. I get SD in the mean column and NA in the SD column...

Comment: Yeah I'll post as a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It helped a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

For the values you can use the package plyr:

```
x
ID    Day    pH
1      1      7
1      1      7.2
1      1      7.1
2      1      7.3
2      1      7.4
2      1      7.2
3      1      7
3      1      7.1
3      1      7.5
4      1      7.3
4      1      7.2
4      1      7.6
1      2      7
1      2      7.2
1      2      7.1
2      2      7.1
2      2      7.4
2      2      7.2
3      2      7.5
3      2      7.1
3      2      7.5
4      2      7.2
4      2      7.2
4      2      7.3
1      3      7.4
1      3      7.2
1      3      7.1
2      3      7.2
2      3      7.4
2      3      7.2
3      3      7.4
3      3      7.2
3      3      7.5
4      3      7.4
4      3      7.2
4      3      7.7
```

```
require(plyr)
d1 <- ddply(x, .(ID, Day), summarize, phMean=mean(pH), pHsd=sd(pH))
d2 <- reshape(d1, v.names=c("phMean", "pHsd"), idvar="ID",     timevar="Day",direction="wide")
rownames(d2) <- d2[,1]
d2 <- t(d2[,-1])

require(gplots)
barplot2(d2[(1:nrow(d2))%%2>0.5,], beside=T, plot.ci=T, 
ci.l=d2[(1:nrow(d2))%%2>0.5,]-d2[(1:nrow(d2))%%2<0.5,],
ci.u=d2[(1:nrow(d2))%%2>0.5,]+d2[(1:nrow(d2))%%2<0.5])
```

Comment: Thanks, I already managed to make the graph using: barplot(matrix(c(Rtest.dat$pH.mean),nr=3), beside=T, 
col=c("black","grey","white"), 
main="pH", names.arg=c("Green", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red"), ylab="pH")
legend("topright", c("Day 1","Day 2","Day 3"), cex=0.6, bty="n", fill=c("black","grey","white")) but I got stuck and have no clue how to add the error bars?!? I was looking online but couldn't figure it out. Hope you can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments and answers, it was very usefull!!

And I already managed to make the graph using:

barplot(matrix(c(Rtest.dat$pH.mean),nr=3), beside=T, col=c("black","grey","white"), main="pH", names.arg=c("Green", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red"), ylab="pH") legend("topright", c("Day 1","Day 2","Day 3"), cex=0.6, bty="n", fill=c("black","grey","white"))

but I got stuck and have no clue how to add the error bars?!? I was looking online but couldn't figure it out. Hope you can help me!!